# What is an example of an etale morphism which does not locally factor as a composition of an open immersion and a finite etale map?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be an etale morphism of schemes. By $f$ factoring locally as a composition of an open immersion and a finite etale map, I mean that for every $x \in X$ there exists an open $U$ of $x$ and an open $V \subset Y$ containing $f(U)$ such that the restriction $f:U \rightarrow V$ factors as $U \hookrightarrow W \rightarrow V$, where $U \hookrightarrow W$ is an open immersion and $W \rightarrow V$ is finite etale.

According to section 7.5 of the "Berkeley lectures" by Scholze and Weinstein, it is not true that every etale $f$ factors locally as a composition of an open immersion and a finite etale map in the category of schemes (though it is true in the category of analytic adic spaces). What is an example of this failure for schemes?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that $f$ factors or just factors locally? If the former, then you can take $Y$ the spectrum of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $X$ that of $\mathbb{Z}[1/2,i]$.

Comment: I meant locally. Thanks, I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ariyan Javanpeykar's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3105171/41415) to a related question gives an example that works. Since you're asking for something *a priori* slightly stronger than in that question (no *local* factorization into open immersion + finite étale, not just no *global* factorization), I'll elaborate. The example is as follows: Let $X = \mathbb{A}^1 \setminus \{0, 2/3\}$, and define a morphism $f\colon X \to \mathbb{A}^1$ by $f(x) = x^2 (x - 1)$. Note that $f$ is étale.

Let $U \subseteq X$ be any open subset containing $1 \in X$, and let $V \subseteq \mathbb{A}^1$ be any open subset such that $f(U) \subseteq V$. Note that $0 = f(1) \in V$. Suppose we have a scheme $W$, an open immersion $j\colon U \to W$, and a finite morphism $h\colon W \to V$ such that $f\rvert_U = h \circ j$. Let $Z \subseteq W$ be the irreducible component containing $j(U)$ (with the reduced induced closed subscheme structure). Irreducible components are closed, and closed immersions are finite, so $g := h\rvert_Z\colon Z \to V$ is finite. Finite morphisms are affine, so $Z$ is affine, irreducible, reduced, 1-dimensional, and birational to $\mathbb{A}^1$, which means $Z$ is an open subscheme of $\mathbb{A}^1$. So $g$ is given by a rational function, but since $g$ agrees with $f$ on a dense open subset, this rational function must be $x^2 (x - 1)$.

But since $g$ is finite, all the fibers have the same degree, so $g^{-1}(0)$ consists of three points, counting multiplicity. Since $x^2 (x - 1)$ is ramified above $0$, this means $g$ (and hence $h$) cannot be étale.

Actually, now that I've written this up, I'm a little confused why this doesn't also give a counterexample for analytic adic spaces. I guess it has to do with the more flexible nature of open immersions in the analytic setting?

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. My intuition is that, in the adic setting, you can take $U$ to be a small disc containing 1, and $V$ to be its image via $f$ ($f$ is open since it is etale). Since 1 is not ramified, $f$ is locally 1-1 at 1 (which is not true in the scheme setting, since open sets are too large), so you can take $U$ and $V$ to be so small that already $U\rightarrow V$ is even an isomorphism. I think this picture at least works in the complex analytic setting.

Comment: @xlord You have to be careful. There are subtelties between maximal vs. non-maximal points. What you're describing is more accurate on the *Berkovich space*, but on the adic space you have to contend with the existence of things like Gauss points having non-trivial specialization. In particular, be careful that your intuition almost makes it seem as though for all $x\in X$ and $y=f(x)$ in $Y$ there exists opens $U$ and $V$ neighborhoods around both with $f(U)\subseteq V$ and $f:U\to V$ finite. This is true around maximal points, and in general if $f$ is partially proper, but not in general.

Comment: @AlexYoucis thanks, I have not thought of non maximal points. It was more like I was trying to explain what was happening only at the (maximal) evaluation at 1 point. Is this argument incorrect then? Do you know a nice formal way to prove in this case $f$ factors locally as a composition of an open immersion and a finite etale map? (I could in principle check this up in Huber's book, but perhaps it is simpler for this example?)

Comment: @xlord Are you asking about Lemma 2.2.8 of Huber's book?

Comment: Yes, this is Lemma 2.2.8 in his book.

Comment: @xlord What is your exact question then? How to prove the claim when you assume that $x$ (and therefore $y$) are maximal points?

Comment: Just for the point x=1. I was under the impression you were saying the sketch in my original comment was incorrect. How would you write it out formally, if not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119862/discussion-between-alex-youcis-and-xlord).